# How to write a subquery in a select clause in linq

Tags: sql, linq

I am trying to best convert the following sql query in to a linq query (query syntax).

SQL query:

```
SELECT e.Id, e.Name, e.Salary, e.DepartmentId, (select d.dept_name from department d where d.dept_id = e.DepartmentId) as dpt
FROM [Employee] e
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Model of combinedDataList  (i.e employee and department) and define the poco class  that You need to retrive.

```cs
var combinedDataList =
    from a in _context.employeeTable
    from b in _Context.department 
    where a.DepartmentId=b.dept_id
    Select new Combinetable (
        Id = a .Id,
        Name = a .Name,
        Salary = a .Salary,
        DeptId = a .DepartmentId
        DepartmentName = b.dept_name 
    ).ToList();
```